# make file project with existing code is missing optimization option in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I choose `new --> make file project` with existing code, in the project properties, I don't see code optimization. But if I create a new C++ project, the code optimization option appears.
What should I do to enable code optimization when I choose `new --> make file project` with existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the project that is not behaving the way you want, go to the project properties dialog and look at  `C/C++ BUild->Tool Chain Editor`. Typically I have found that the selection of the `Current toochain:` and `Current builder:` affects what options and tabs show up in the other areas. Once you apply the proper toolchain, your optimization settings should be present.